# Android Using tinyalsa in Java code

Tags: android, android-ndk, tinyalsa

I built tinyalsa lib using the sources from [tinyalsa-ndk](https://github.com/ykasidit/tinyalsa-ndk/) and wrapped it with JNI calls and I'm trying to use it in my code.

I used [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) to generate Java wrappers (and modified output to comply with my package)
My native method declaration is:

```
public final static native long mixer_open(long jarg);
```

My JNI wrapper call is inside a wrapper class TinyAlsa.java under the root pacakge (for the example I'll use com.Example.App):

```
public static SWIGTYPE_p_mixer mixer_open(long card) 
{
    long cPtr = TinyAlsaJNI.mixer_open(card);
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_mixer(cPtr, false);
}
```

and my wrapper c method is:

```
SWIGEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_Example_App_Native_TinyAlsaJNI_mixer_1open(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1) 
{
    jlong jresult = 0 ;
    unsigned int arg1 ;
    struct mixer *result = 0 ;

    (void)jenv;
    (void)jcls;
    arg1 = (unsigned int)jarg1; 
    result = (struct mixer *)mixer_open(arg1);
    *(struct mixer **)&jresult = result; 
    return jresult;
}
```

The tinalsa library is loaded OK without exceptions but calls such as `mixer_open(0)` returns null pointers.
However If I execute the compiled tinymix mixer is open and mixer controls are listed as should.
Am I missing something? How can I make it work from my code?

Comment: Code would probably make it easier to tell what you're missing

Comment: Deleted my answer as I realize I misread your code.  But you are overcomplicating the return- just change it to return (long long)mixer_open(arg1);      You may be missing some init code, I'd put a log or breakpoint in this function to see if open itself is returning NULL.  If so, you are missing some sort of init function.

Comment: The c code is generated using Swig. I suspect it indeed over complicates things, but - as this code eventually access mixer info which is most likely not permitted without root, I'm trying to figure whether I should do something else to make it work (besides calling su before calling alsa methods), if the code itself is not the problem..